# How did Marius make it to Mephisto's secret lair in Diablo2?

Tags: video-games, diablo

As a novice player I found it extremely difficult to get to Mephisto's lair, despite being the game's hero! You make a step and [40-50 demon-like creatures jump on you](https://youtu.be/vq9ngOyLU6Y?t=2m29s), not even mentioning the crazy mobs in Zakarum, etc...

**How a very weak character like Marius even make it to Mephisto's secret lair in a world full with about *10 monsters for every square metre?***

Comment: I think they are correlated. But I am not sure. Do you advice to delete the second one ?

Comment: I think you are right I edited my question.

Comment: I assume that the difficulty of gameplay does not correlate with the character’s in-universe skills.

Comment: I've not played this, but a casual look at some gameplay vids seem to show characters using some kind of portal to teleport between locations. Could he be using those to get around?

Comment: You're confusing things.  The demons became more active after Marius and the Dark Wanderer entered an area.  Also, the presence of the Wanderer caused the demons to cower and not interact with them.

Comment: @CBredlow very good answer makes sense to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They weren't nearly as active as they were during the events of Diablo 2.  Deckard even mentions that when the player shows up to the rogue encampment in Act 1.  Areas change a lot after the Dark Wanderer passes through an area, and normally peaceful places become chaotic, and the monsters become a lot worse.

This is mostly due to the Dark Wander

> being Diablo

Comment: It doesn't actually say anywhere on this page that Marius was the Dark Wanderer's companion, and would have been moving through the Durance with or close behind the Dark Wanderer. But it does now.